# Rust Read CSV without header

Tags: csv, rust

How does one read a CSV without a header in Rust? I've searched through the docs and gone through like 15 examples each of which is subtly not what I'm looking for.

Consider how easy Python makes it:

```py
csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=['city'])
```

How do you do this in Rust?

Current attempt:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct CityRow {
    city: &str,
    pop: u32,
}

fn doit() -> zip::result::ZipResult<()>
{
    let filename = "cities.csv";
    let mut zip = zip::ZipArchive::new(File::open(filename).unwrap())?;
    let mut file = zip.by_index(0).unwrap();
    println!("Filename: {}", file.name());
    let mut reader = csv::Reader::from_reader(Box::new(file));
    reader.set_headers(csv::StringRecord([  "city", "pop" ]));

    for record in reader.records() {
        // let record: CityRow = record.unwrap();
        // let record = record?;
        println!("{:?}", record);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: In the Python example you're using the Pandas library to manage your data. Are you using a similar DataFrame library (such as [polars](https://crates.io/crates/polars)) to manage your data in your Rust code?

Comment: Apologies, no, just reading a normal csv like the csv crate examples, but without a header.

Comment: Could you add how you're currently using the `csv` crate to extract the rows to your question? There are a few ways of doing it (main difference is if you're using Serde). [`csv::ReaderBuilder::has_headers`](https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/struct.ReaderBuilder.html#method.has_headers) might help, but I can't test that without seeing the code.

Comment: Sure thing, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `ReaderBuilder`, and call [`ReaderBuilder::has_headers`](https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/struct.ReaderBuilder.html#method.has_headers) to disable header parsing. You can then use [`StringRecord::deserialize`](https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/struct.StringRecord.html#method.deserialize) to extract and print each record, skipping the first header row:

```
let mut reader = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
    .has_headers(false)
    .from_reader(Box::new(file));

let headers = csv::StringRecord::from(vec!["city", "pop"]);
for record in reader.records().skip(1) {
    let record: CityRow = record.unwrap().deserialize(Some(&headers)).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", record);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3c8d74247a53ae0d4677ff270849a1f0)

Answer (score 2):

@smitop's answer didn't totally make sense to me [when looking at the underlying code](https://docs.rs/csv/latest/src/csv/reader.rs.html#873) since the library appears to assume headers will exist by default. This means actually the below should work directly, and I found it did:

```
    let mut reader = csv::Reader::from_reader(data.as_bytes());
    
    for record in reader.deserialize() {
        let record: CityRow = record.unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", record);
    }
```

I checked through the variants in this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c52cc70279cb4dfe95f8b77eded76284).

For what it's worth, it turned out in my case I had accidentally left a code path in that was reading my csv as a plain file, which is why I had seen headers read as a row. (Oops.)